# Has anyone seen this bug in chrome, using background gifs?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, animated-gif

In chrome 35 running on Mavericks, while using an animated gif as a background, gif only animates while user is scrolling, it's really strange, this only happens if the background is fixed, and only after the first element with a gif background

[here](http://codepen.io/javiercf/pen/AnkmI) is a demo I placed in codepen

Comment: I certainly see it in Chrome/Mavericks. It's quite odd, but in a way, it's kind of a cool effect!

Comment: @ralph.m I totally agree! part of the reason I wan't to know if anyone has encountered this issue is to replicate the behaviour in other browsers using js or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is not a bug but rather a the way Google Chrome is made.

Firefox and other browsers have ways to stop the GIF's from animating while Chrome doesn't (Unless you use extensions.)

Here is a feature in Firefox for changing the settings of animated GIFS:

- Open Firefox and type `about:config` in the address bar then press
  Enter. Click the `“I’ll be careful I Promise”` warning button to reveal
  a long list of preferences.
- Look for the entry `image.animation_mode` (its default value should
  `normal`).
- Double click the entry and set its value to `none` to completely
  disable image animation.
- Double click the entry and set its value to `once` instead to make the
  GIF images animate only once.

However, in Chrome, There is no menu option to disable animations.
Even when using Chrome's extensions to disable GIF extensions, **as soon as you scroll up/down the page the animations play once whilst a new screenshot is overlaid.**